# showing input after selecting other in a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a dynamic table I have a dropdown list where I have "other", and I would like to have additional input when I select "other".
However, this function only hides the input that is always visible, and does not show when other is selected. I don't know how to change this function.

```js
jQuery('[id^="insurer_multi["]').each(function() {
  var thisId = jQuery(this).attr('id');
  var index = thisId.substring(thisId.indexOf('[') + 1, thisId.indexOf(']'));

  if (jQuery(`[id="insurer_multi[${index}]`) == "other") {
    jQuery(`[id="Postal_multiply[${index}]`).val("jazda");
  } else {
    jQuery(`[id="insurer_multi_add[${index}]`).hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col col-1">
      <select class="small" id="insurer_multi" name="insurer_multi" data-timsupport="dropdown" data-timdatasource="insurer" data-timdisplaytype="label" index="field1">
        <option>other</option>
        <option>noother</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="insurer_multi_add" data-timsupport="number" data-timnumberofdigits="0" name="insurer_multi_add" class="small" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col col-1">
      <select class="small" id="insurer_multi" name="insurer_multi" data-timsupport="dropdown" data-timdatasource="insurer" data-timdisplaytype="label" index="field1">
        <option>other</option>
        <option>noother</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="insurer_multi_add" data-timsupport="number" data-timnumberofdigits="0" name="insurer_multi_add" class="small" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col col-1">
      <select class="small" id="insurer_multi" name="insurer_multi" data-timsupport="dropdown" data-timdatasource="insurer" data-timdisplaytype="label" index="field1">
        <option>other</option>
        <option>noother</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="insurer_multi_add" data-timsupport="number" data-timnumberofdigits="0" name="insurer_multi_add" class="small" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first issue in your code is because you're attempting to work around the fact that you have used dynamically generated incremental `id` attributes in your HTML. This is making your JS much more complicated than it needs to be.

To improve your code and fix the issue, change these `id` attributes to common `class` instead. You can then attach the event handler to them usnig that class and traverse the DOM to find the `input` related to the `select` which triggered the event. You can then hide/show that `input` based on the selected value.

Here's a working example:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('table').on('change', '.insurer_multi', e => {
    let $el = $(e.target);
    $el.next('input.insurer_multi_add').toggle($el.val() === 'other');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="col col-1">
      <select class="small insurer_multi" name="insurer_multi" data-timsupport="dropdown" data-timdatasource="insurer" data-timdisplaytype="label" index="field1">
        <option>other</option>
        <option>noother</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" data-timsupport="number" data-timnumberofdigits="0" name="insurer_multi_add" class="small insurer_multi_add" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col col-1">
      <select class="small insurer_multi" name="insurer_multi" data-timsupport="dropdown" data-timdatasource="insurer" data-timdisplaytype="label" index="field1">
        <option>other</option>
        <option>noother</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" data-timsupport="number" data-timnumberofdigits="0" name="insurer_multi_add" class="small insurer_multi_add" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="col col-1">
      <select class="small insurer_multi" name="insurer_multi" data-timsupport="dropdown" data-timdatasource="insurer" data-timdisplaytype="label" index="field1">
        <option>other</option>
        <option>noother</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" data-timsupport="number" data-timnumberofdigits="0" name="insurer_multi_add" class="small insurer_multi_add" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have two questions. How can I hide insurer_multi_add in jQuery, no access to CSS ?

Comment: `$('.input.insurer_multi_add').hide()` - although you shouldn't need to, as the code above handles this for you through `toggle()`

Comment: I dont know but your function is not working for my side and not showing any errors, i changed html and add JS

Comment: i add here whole my table, https://jsfiddle.net/Palucci92/36knwxta/1/ could you check why your code ther not working. Other is added to CSV. file not coded in HTML

Comment: That fiddle didn't include any `option` element with the 'other' text, nor did it include jQuery. When you fix both of those problems then the code above works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/9eaxqs6t/